# TailWindCSS Super Config

Tags: css, postcss, tailwind-css

So I want to make a TailWindCSS Super Config in which I have every height fraction up-to 12, same for height screen and font size, and a lot of colours.

> I know that TailWindCSS gives a pretty good default config, but I want it bigger, better.
> FileSize is not an issue for the CSS and it is going to be Purged, after working with PurgeCSS for a little while, I feel confident that it will only include what is needed.
>
> Having a large StyleSheet does mean that some developers may take it too far and start to overuse classes, however I personally feel that this will not be an issue within my company, and I would still like to have a large config.
>
> I want to automatically generate the config so that I can have the 1/2, 2/3, 5/5 etc generated without me having to enter them manually into the config, along with this I want every variant for every attribute, making the end CSS even bigger!

In Short, I would like a way to generate some of the config automatically, and I want to know the correct order to declare the config (EG: height, width, box shadow etc).

Thanks, Justin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the result of my investigations is just to use the native ability of Javascript to generate parts of the config automatically, saving me time writing out config lines.

```js
myVariants = {};

for(let x = 1; x < 12; x++)
  myVariants[x + "/12"] = (8.33333 * x) + "%";

console.log(myVariants);
```

There is much more you can do to make your config even more automated too!

Answer (score 1):

Everything that you mentioned you can do it easily with the default config file that TailwindCSS gives you

This is the beauty of TailwindCSS, easy configuration, unlimited choices

Try https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration

Example:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
 theme: { 
  extend: {
   colors: {
    'lollipop': {
       100: '#FFFFEE',
       200: '#FFFFD5',
       300: '#FFFFBB',
       400: '#FFFE88',
       500: '#FFFE55',
       600: '#E6E54D',
       700: '#999833',
       800: '#737226',
       900: '#4D4C1A',
    },
    'lola': {
       100: '#FCFBFC',
       200: '#F8F4F7',
       300: '#F4EDF1',
       400: '#EBE0E7',
       500: '#E3D3DD',
       600: '#CCBEC7',
       700: '#887F85',
       800: '#665F63',
       900: '#443F42',
    }
   },
   spacing: {
    '96': '24rem',
    '128': '32rem',
    '254': '64rem',
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I know this is a late reply, but reading-over my original question this doesn't quite solve it, I wanted to have the config automatically generated. Luckily, as the config is just JS, we can solve this quite easily. I'll post another answer covering what I did, but thanks, have a good day!